# Make div display hidden or block when a checkbox is unchecked or checked

Tags: html, css

The goal of the code is that when you click the hamburger icon, the 'hamburger-list' will appear. But when i click the icon the checkbox('hamburger-list-dropdown-checkbox') gets checked successfully but the lists' display doesn't change to block
Here's the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <title>FFG</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="hamburger-list-dropdown-select">
        <input type="checkbox" class="hamburger-list-dropdown-checkbox absolute">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-list"
            viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                d="M2.5 12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5m0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5m0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5">
            </path>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="hamburger-list">
        <ul>
            <li>foo</li>
            <li>bar</li>
            <li>baz</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And here's the css

```
#hamburger-list-dropdown-select{
    position: absolute;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
}
.hamburger-list-dropdown-checkbox{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.hamburger-list{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    top: 40px;
    display: none;
}

.hamburger-list-dropdown-checkbox:checked + .hamburger-list{
    display: block;
}
.absolute{
    position: absolute;
}
```

I couldn't think of anything to solve the issue, hope you guys can help :)

Comment: You're using the element selector `+` wrong. The element with the class `hamburger-list-dropdown-checkbox` doesn't have a subsequent element with the class `hamburger-list`. You might want to move the logic to it's parent and use `:has()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has - Try something along `#hamburger-list-dropdown-select:has(checkbox:checked) + .hamburger-list`

Comment: It worked, just had to change 'checkbox:checked' to 'input: checked' so the final form is
**'#hamburger-list-dropdown-select:has(input:checked) + .hamburger-list'**

Comment: Ah yes, input sry :-) Might as well use your class name, just in case you're gonna add a second checkbox in there some day.